# Adding AD group with python-ldap

Tags: python, active-directory, python-ldap

I am trying to create group within AD with no success, below is my code:

```
import ldap
import ldap.modlist as modlist

LDAPserver = 'hidden'
LDAPlogin = 'hidden'
LDAPpassword = 'hidden'

l = ldap.initialize('ldap://' + LDAPserver)

l.simple_bind_s(LDAPlogin, LDAPpassword)

dn = 'OU=someunit,OU=someunit,OU=someunit,OU=someunit,DC=my-company,DC=local'

attrs = {}
attrs['objectclass'] = ['top','Group']
attrs['cn'] = 'group name to be created'
attrs['description'] = 'Test Group'

ldif = modlist.addModlist(attrs)

l.add_s(dn,ldif)

l.unbind_s()
```

Following snippet gives me an error:

```
ldap.INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS: {'info': '00000005: SecErr: DSID-031521D0, problem 4003 
(INSUFF_ACCESS_RIGHTS), data 0\n', 'desc': 'Insufficient access'}
```

However, using same credentials I can create group with some UI tools like [LDAP Admin](http://www.ldapadmin.org/)

so I suppose that I have proper permissions to create groups, but still no success with python-ldap.

I can also query existing groups and fetch its members via script.

I believe that the problem is in my attributes, maybe Active Directory need some different values to be inserted into **attrs** variable. AD is running under Win Server 2012 R2.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

The `dn` should actually be `CN=<groupname>` + `base_dn`, so in your case something like

```
dn = 'CN=groupname,OU=someunit,OU=someunit,OU=someunit,OU=someunit,DC=my-company,DC=local'
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try to replace `LDAPlogin` to a full bind `dn` value such as

```
"cn=hidden,dc=example,dc=com"
```